# TSQL calculating sum of numerous fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops

I have this kind of data:

```
Date         Count1 Count2 Count3 ... Countxx
01-05-2012   1      0      1          2
01-05-2012   2      1      3          0
01-05-2012   2      3      3          1
02-05-2012   1      3      2          0
02-05-2012   5      2      0          0
```

and I need to calculate sum of respective fields (Count1 to Countxx) grouped by date and wrote this SQL:

```
select sum(count1), sum(count2), sum(count3), .. , sum(countxx) 
from table1 group by date
```

my first question: is there any way in SQL server to do this automatically (without knowing number of fields, since the name and number of the fields will be different each time, thus making writing the SQL manually very cumbersome).

secondly, how to calculate value from current row minus previous row, and average of previous 7 rows?

Thanks!

Comment: "thus making writing the SQL manually very cumbersome" - so don't write it manually. Get the computer to write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
create procedure USP_FindSum @tablename varchar(100)                
as
begin
 create table #temp(id int identity(1,1),name varchar(100))
 declare @sqlcmd nvarchar(max)=''
 SET @sqlcmd= N'Insert into #temp select name from sys.columns col_table where        
 col_table.object_id=object_id('''+@tablename+''')'
 EXEC sp_executesql @sqlcmd
 declare @sqlseg varchar(max)=''
 declare @tempcount int
 declare @i int=1
 select @tempcount=COUNT(id) from #temp
 while(@i<=@tempcount)
 BEGIN
   declare @CName varchar(100)
   SELECT @CName= name from #temp where id=@i
   if(@i!=@tempcount)
    SET @sqlseg=+@sqlseg+'sum('+@CName+')'+',' 
   else
    SET @sqlseg =+@sqlseg+'sum('+@CName+')'
   SET @i=@i+1
 END
 SET @sqlcmd=N'select '+@sqlseg+' from '+@tablename
 EXEC sp_executesql @sqlcmd
 DROP TABLE #temp
END
```

**Assuming all the columns in the table are summable**. As your requirement is weird this workaround may also be so.

Just pass the table name as parameter and execute,

`Exec USP_FindSum '<tablename here>'`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sum a variable list of columns, you have to specify them all.

One way to look up the previous row is `outer apply`, like:

```
select  Date
,       cur.count1 - isnull(prev.count1,0) as Delta1
from    Table1 cur
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    Table1 prev
        where   prev.Date < cur.Date
        order by
                prev.Date desc
        ) prev
```

Another way is to join the tables based on `row_number()`:

```
; with  t1 as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by Date) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        )
select  Date,
,       cur.count1 - isnull(prev.count1,0) as Delta
from    t1 cur
left join    
        t1 prev
on      cur.rn = prev.rn + 1
```