# Single SQL Query to update datatypes of all columns in a table at one shot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server table which has 625 columns created with different datatypes like `int`, `varchar(25)`, `decimal(18, 2)`, etc...

Now am interested in changing datatype of all columns to `varchar(255)`. Instead of executing below query for all the columns one by one, is there a single SQL Server query to change datatypes of all columns in a table at one shot?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee 
ALTER COLUMN FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

Looking forward for your response.

Comment: Changing **all** datatypes to `VARCHAR(255)` doesn't sound like a smart move; after all, those datatypes exist for a reason - why are you giving up on those datatypes? But no - there is no "magic T-SQL" to change all column to a new datatype - you'll basically have to do this column by column - or create a cursor over the `sys.columns` entries for that table and execute the `ALTER TABLE ..` statement for each column

Comment: You are right marc_s, but i have a requirement like that. can this be done in a single sql query?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047551/tsql-calculating-sum-of-numerous-fields/11049198#11049198].. tat may help you..(similar to your concept)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no one single "magic" bullet to do this - it's an operation that's rather unusual, so it's not supported natively.

What you can do is iterate over the columns of your table from the system catalog views, create such an ALTER statement on the fly, and also execute it - something like this:

```
DECLARE AlterTableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
FOR
    SELECT 
        AlterCmd = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere ALTER COLUMN ' + name + ' VARCHAR(255) NULL'
    FROM 
        sys.columns
    WHERE 
        object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTableNameHere')

DECLARE @AlterTableCmd NVARCHAR(200)

OPEN AlterTableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM AlterTableCursor INTO @AlterTableCmd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC (@AlterTableCmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM AlterTableCursor INTO @AlterTableCmd
END

CLOSE AlterTableCursor
DEALLOCATE AlterTableCursor
```

Replace the `YourTableNameHere` with your actual table name - and you should be good to go! **Test this** on a **copy of your live data** first !

Answer (score 4):

is not possible. You will need to do this one by one. You can do following things -

1. You can create a Temporary Table with your desired columns and type.
2. copy the data from original table to temporary table.
3. delete original table
4. Rename you Temporary Table to your original name

Comment: In order to do this, it takes lot of time changing datatype for all columns while creating table, We can follow above procedure but am thinking to do in a very less time

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it's not a good design to have 625 columns in one table, but you do what ever you have been asked to do.

You could generate a `SQL` string that contains multiple `ALTER` statements and execute it with `EXEC`. You have to be careful with the data conversion though. This is why it's probably better to do it in a cursor, because you can catch possible exceptions for the columns that cannot be altered. Here is a simple code which does it in two steps:

- generate the `SQL` string;
- execute it using `EXEC`

Code sample:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'Employee'

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = (
SELECT '
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ALTER COLUMN ' + c.name + ' VARCHAR(255) NULL;
'
FROM sys.columns c WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'Employee'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'Employee'
```