# SQL Server 2008 mass alter statement for data type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, text, varchar

I am trying to change data type from `text` to `varchar` in all of my tables at once.

This query

```
  select *
  from information_schema.columns
  where data_type = 'text'
```

shows me all of my `text` data types, but how do I use this to then alter type to `varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy these commands from query result and execute them:

```
    select 
        cmd = 'alter table [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name + '] alter column [' + c.column_name + '] varchar(<yoursize>)'
        ,*
    from information_schema.columns c
    where c.data_type='text'
```

But:

- you need to join tables information to select only tables (query above would return views, too)
- it won't let you alter some columns, e.g. with PK/FK constrints
- this select may list also tables that you don't want to / cannot modify. E.g. sysdiagrams
- It's generally not a good idea to do it like tht if you're not limiting it to few tables that you exactly know the structure of.

Comment: Right idea, but this will dangerously set every column to the instance's default nullability, won't filter out views, and will return a row for every column regardless of datatype (meaning more manual work for the DBA).

Answer (score 1):

I would change all of your `text`, `ntext` and `image` datatypes to the newer `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` datatypes:

```
select 'alter table ' + quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)
    + ' alter column ' + quotename(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' '
    + case c.DATA_TYPE when 'image' then 'varbinary(max)' when 'ntext' then 'nvarchar(max)' when 'text' then 'varchar(max)' end + ' '
    + case c.IS_NULLABLE when 'YES' then 'not' else '' end + ' null;' as SqlCommand
    , *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
        and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        and c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
where c.DATA_TYPE in ('image', 'ntext', 'text')
    and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Simply copy and run the SqlCommand column as a batch.

This will handle nullability and filter-out views.

I don't believe you can put any type unique constraint on a text/ntext/image column, so you probably don't have to check for PK/FK/UK.  You would have to account for other types of constraints and defaults, however.  If you have a lot of those, it might be easier to make these changes in SSMS diagram mode.

Answer (score 0):

At first it may seem as simple as this:

1. Use a cursor loop over the select from information_schema.
2. Compose dynamic SQL for each column of interest that will change its datatype using an ALTER TABLE statement.
3. Execute the dynamic SQL.

However, you need to drop any indices on these columns first, foreign key constraints, etc.
Then when you are done, you can recreate the constraints and indices.

See this SO question:

[Single SQL Query to update datatypes of all columns in a table at one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150705/single-sql-query-to-update-datatypes-of-all-columns-in-a-table-at-one-shot)